# Cordova --> Android Target : not installed

Tags: android, android-studio, apache-cordova

I'm trying to make an android app using Cordova.
When I run the command Cordova requirements it errors by android target not installed

When i tried to build the app it says Android_Home variable is deprecated, Android_sdk_root (recommended setting)

[image: Android target not installed.]

[image: Android_Home variable is deprecated.]

My questions are:

1. How can I solve android target however i've installed the latest android studio ?
2. Is the Android_Home (Deprecated) is a problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer which is..

Please Install Android API 28-android

In this link i found all Api levels
https://source.android.com/setup/start/build-numbers

API level 28-android is Pie
Then i installed Pie SDK tools from SDK Manager and it runs well.